# Convert csv column into list using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm currently working on a project that takes a csv list of student names who attended a meeting, and converts it into a list (later to be compared to full student roster list, but one thing at a time). I've been looking for answers for hours but I still feel stuck. I've tried using both pandas and the csv module. I'd like to stick with pandas, but if it's easier in the csv module that works too. CSV file example and code below.

The file is autogenerated by our video call software- so the formatting is a little weird.

Attendance.csv
[see sample as image, I can't insert images yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvjEi.png)

Code:

```
data = pandas.read_csv("2A Attendance Report.csv", header=3)
AttendanceList = data['A'].to_list()

print(str(AttendanceList))
```

However, this is raising KeyError: 'A'

Any help is really appreciated, thank you!!!

Comment: Is `A` in the third row? Why `header=3`?

Comment: Since you had `header=3`, your column name probably would've changed to `"Full Names"`.
Try `data.columns` or `data.head()` to check your column name

Comment: I really appreciate the help!! I found the problem, there were a bunch of null characters in the csv file that had to be removed. Everything works now. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

As seen in sample image, you have column headers in the first row itself. Hence you need to remove `header=3` from your `read_csv` call. Either replace it with `header=0` or don't specify any explicit header value at all.

Comment: I really appreciate the help!! I found the problem, there were a bunch of null characters in the csv file that had to be removed. Everything works now. Thanks!!